# Remove File Intermittently Fails

Tags: python

I am working on Windows 7 64 bit with Python 3.6,

I am trying to download a series of files from various locations on the Internet. Once I am done with the downloaded file I delete it and download the next one. I am downloading with `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` and that seems to work fine.

Every once in a while (maybe 1 out of 50 or 100 attempts) I can't remove the file I downloaded. I receive the error, "Access is Denied." After the exception if I navigate to the file I was trying to delete in Windows explorer it is there and doesn't have any restricted permissions associated with it.

Can anyone give me some idea about how to make this work?

Here is the code in question:

```
    if os.path.isfile(filePath):

        try:

            os.remove(filePath)

        except OSError as e:

            print("Failed with:", e.strerror)
            print("Error code:", e.code)
            print("Can't remove file: ", filePath)
            write_to_log("Can't remove file: ", filePath)
```

Edit:

In response to the comment, I am downloading with the method mentioned above.

I do open, read, and modify the file at least once before I attempt to delete it, so I had suspected that maybe Windows thought it was still open.

I guess my question now is, how do I check to see if the file is delete-able? Is there some way I can wait if Windows is holding onto it still?

Edit (again):

I tried this on my Ubuntu Linux machine (with different paths, of course), and it seems to work fine, so it is definitely a Windows issue.

Comment: Is it possible that the file is still open when you try to delete it? I suspect that Windows won't allow you to delete a file that is still open.

Comment: IIRC, you can use Process Explorer to determine which process or processes have a file open and then debug your process from there. It's a free download.

Comment: As per @Attie, Windows does in fact not let you delete open files. Can you post the code that downloads the files so that we can see if there's a problem there?